# How to convert Hex characters to ASCII using sed & regex

Tags: regex, sed, character-encoding

I've a file with several special characters coded in hexa (the other words are readable).
I would like to use sed to convert them using \xHH but I'm not able to do it using regex to match hexa values to translate.

If I manually force the **Hexa** value it works:

```
[user@Centos7]$ echo "aaa&#xED;aaa" | sed -r 's/&#x([[:xdigit:]]+);/\xED/g'
aaaíaaa
```

But if I try to **reuse the match from my regex** to translate it to ACSII value using \xHH, it failed => the result is \x + the value matched

```
[user@Centos7]$ echo "aaa&#xED;aaa" | sed -r 's/&#x([[:xdigit:]]+);/\x\1/g'
aaaxEDaaa
```

Any clue to help me for this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Note: `\xED` is not ascii (ASCII do not have accented characters, it is just a subset of common characters used in English). I would go near your second way, but adding '\`, and doing an additional eval with echo

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not better using echo and ` (or maybe my command is still not the good one:
``` 
    [user@Centos7]$ echo "aaa&#xED;aaa" | sed -r 's/&#x([[:xdigit:]]+);/`echo \x\1`/g'
aaa`echo xED`aaa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with `perl` using [`MHTML::Entities`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities):

```sh
echo 'aaa&#xED;aaa' | perl -MHTML::Entities -CS -pe '$_ = decode_entities($_)'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/9ImSFT).

Here,

- Due to `-CS` Perl allows UTF-8 characters in the STDOUT
- `decode_entities($string)` routine replaces HTML entities found in the `$string` with the corresponding Unicode character (nrecognized entities are left as is).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, it works well!
I just had to install "yum install perl-HTML-Parser.x86_64" to be able to use your command.